# LARGE_INTEGER and DUMMYSTRUCTNAME

Tags: c++

When I come across the definition of LARGE_INTEGER. I find some questions:

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

Can We rewrite as follows:

```
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        DWORD LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

I think the struct u is duplicate. So why MSVC implement LARGE_INTEGER as this? I wonder maybe some reason like compatibility.

Comment: **Best Guess**. `LARGE_INTEGER` has been in the Windows SDK forever. And they probably needed the `u` part for compiling as "C" code on a very old version of the compiler that expected named types back in the day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is apparently an adjustment to avoid having an anonymous structure in a union.  This had been supported by Visual C++, but is not allowed in by the language standard.  (See [can't make sense of LARGE_INTEGER struct](/questions/3606902/cant-make-sense-of-large-integer-struct) for a declaration of the struct without the `DUMMYSTRUCTNAME`.)  The name would have been added to bring the union into conformance with standard C++, possibly with some sort of automated tool.

[Later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-_large_integer) of `LARGE_INTEGER` get rid of the structs entirely and just have the `QuadPart`.