# C: How to interpret the union containing 2 struct objects? ULARGE_INTEGER

Tags: c, winapi, struct, unions

I have a question about the interpretation of this `union` object.

From the win32 API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-ularge_integer-r1

```
typedef union _ULARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    DWORD HighPart;
  } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
  struct {
    DWORD LowPart;
    DWORD HighPart;
  } u;
  ULONGLONG QuadPart;
} ULARGE_INTEGER;
```

This is a `union` so the `LowPart` and `HighPart` of each struct in the union reference the low and high 32 bit words of the object `QuadPart`, which is a 64 bit word aka `ULONGLONG`.

My question is: Why are two structs contained inside this union?

Unless I misunderstand `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME::LowPart` references the same bits in memory as `u::LowPart`. And the same in the case of `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME::HighPart` and `u::HighPart`.

Why are the two names `u` and `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME` used here?

> Inb4 "should be `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME.LowPart`" (?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LARGE\_INTEGER and DUMMYSTRUCTNAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52732164/large-integer-and-dummystructname)

Comment: It does in combination with this question (which was linked in an answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606902/cant-make-sense-of-large-integer-struct

Comment: It turns out that they used to use an anonymous struct for convenience sake, but this isn't supported by the C standard, so it was "removed" by adding the word `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME`. Why that is required for backwards compatability I do not understand, since code would have to be changed to use `.DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME.LowPart` or `.u.LowPart`... Strange?

Comment: `DUMMYSTRUCTURENAME` is likely to be a `#define` that translates to nothing under some circumstances controlled by `#ifdef`s.

Comment: @user3386109 it is indeed a `#define`, in `winnt.h`: `#ifndef DUMMYSTRUCTNAME
#if defined(NONAMELESSUNION) || !defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS) #define DUMMYSTRUCTNAME  s ... #else #define DUMMYSTRUCTNAME ... #endif #endif` (the `...` defines `DUMMYSTRUCTNAME2` .. `DUMMYSTRUCTNAME5` in the same manner)  See [What are anonymous structs, and more importantly, how do I tell windows.h to stop using them?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170907-00/?p=96956)

Comment: Ok, then it makes sense